# Relate application to new buildpack

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack

I've created a new buildpack for testing, and I want my application to use this build pack. Previously, I put a reference to the custom build pack like the following:

cf push my_app -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-nodejs.git

However, my buildpack was created locally. What are the steps I should take to use this new buildpack?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can upload your custom buildpack from your local file system. Use the `cf-create-buildpack` command, and for the path argument supply the local directory where your created buildpack lives. Alternatively, you can zip it up and provide the zip file as an argument.

Documentation for this feature can be found here:
http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/buildpacks.html

Comment: This relies on the user being an administrator for their CF org. This will not be normal for most users.

Answer (score -1):

Using a custom buildpack with your application relies on having the [buildpack available at a remote Git URL](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html#deploying-with-custom-buildpacks).

Push your local buildpack to a new repository on Github and use the remote address with the command line '-b' option or in the manifest file.

Comment: James, your answer is correct for the specific commercial distribution of Cloud Foundry that you support, but it is not true for the Cloud Foundry product in general. I managed to be respectful and bring another perspective without editing or downvoting your answer. If you can be equally respectful, it can benefit the Cloud Foundry community as a whole.

Comment: Apologies if you thought I was not being respectful. It's clear from the documentation that normal users of any CF platform will not be able to install buildpacks. I believed the answer, while technically correct, was misleading and not useful for normal CF users. It looks like you've downvoted my answer in response. Nice work...

Comment: James, as I said, I have not downvoted your response, nor have I edited your comment (if you need me to prove this, I can downvote you to -2 for demo). You are defining "most users" and "normal users" as customers of your specific hosted implementation. Many people posting here are running their own installations of Cloud Foundry, or are running on-premises installations where they can obtain administrative privileges for their development org.

Comment: The comment you left on my answer was completely appropriate (although you should probably qualify your own answer as well since it only applies to some cases). Editing my answer and downvoting me is not helpful. Getting into downvote wars would only degrade the content for users looking for help. We should focus on providing better content and more perspectives for users instead of trying to "win" against other people who are being helpful.